# Flutter App is not working after changing package name

Tags: android, firebase, dart, package, flutter

I am trying to release my apk and just changed the com.example package name to my own com.[companynamehere].[appname] in the AndroidManifest.xml file and app/build.gradle file, however now my app stops working as soon as i run it. any idea what might be the problem? is there anywhere else i need to change the package name? I'm also using firebase and i generated a new google-services.json file with the new package name.

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and then build again.

Comment: Deleting `.vscode/launch.json` worked for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md#reason-7

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You also need to update your package name in: Mainactivity.java

Update: If you have enabled Kotlin, you should update your package name in Mainactivity.kt