# Flutter stuck at Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, flutter-release, flutter-android

When I run:

```
$ flutter run
```

I'm getting a prompt on my mobile device asking if I want to install the app on my device. I give yes, then nothing happens!

It's stuck here:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on POCO F1 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                           1.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                        9.2s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  22.9s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                     14.9s
```

Then nothing.

Comment: What Flutter version?

Comment: the latest beta is 0.11.7, make sure you use that.

Comment: Can you post flutter doctor log here? Also are you installing on emulator or actual device, since I faced the same issue when I was trying to install on actual iphone device connected through wifi.

Comment: post `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Vishnu's solution worked for me, see my comments there for my Flutter version.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, I made a mistake and changed the `<application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. This caused the problem for me.

Comment: in my case i have tried all solution on comment but doesnt work. i have ever work by uninstall all for users , but now its not working . then when i restart my phone , try re run its just working as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved this by manually installing the apk file generated in the builds folder. After that running `flutter run` runs the app on my phone.

Comment: This worked for me. I am running Flutter (Channel master, v1.1.10-pre.98, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523], locale en-AU), my device is a real Android 9 on Nokia 7.1.

Comment: yeah working but how to hot reload for debug like as usually we run from main.dart on vscode by click run in the top of code ```void main() async {``` . ?

Answer (score 113):

For me, the error was due to my work android profile. I uninstalled the debug app in personal profile but it remained in the work profile, once I uninstalled it there and ran flutter run. It worked without any issues.
So,
First, ensure you deleted the App in both personal and work profile
And then run

```sh
flutter run
```

#### Update:

By profiles I meant, android user profiles on your phone.

Comment: This was issue for me. On the device, open `Settings` > `Apps` > Find your app & select it > Click on `...` at top right > `Delete for all users`. Once complete, run again and it should install.

Comment: Delete apps for all users works great. Thanks

Comment: hah. it's worked. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

I removed debug application from Android menu, and then I ran into the same issue. I restarted my phone, but it wasn't very helpful. My solution was to **remove the application completely and reinstall it** by hand:

1. Connect to the device with ADB
2. Use `adb uninstall com.example.application.name`
3. Use `adb install C:\PathToYourProject\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk`

By the way, in such uneasy scenarios, `flutter run --verbose` could provide more detailed information what went wrong.

Comment: An alternative is to go to settings->apps & notifications->See all apps and delete the app in question. In my case, it said it was installed but not for "this user". I went to the 3 dots and choose uninstall for all users. That fixed it.

Comment: Just adding to Aron's comment, I have found occasions where deleting from the settings page has still somehow left a reference to the application that only uninstalling from adb can solve.

Comment: Just "adb uninstall com.example.application.name" helped me to solve this issue Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this issue after changing my package name. Following the instructions on this post helped me: [Flutter App is not working after changing package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283117/flutter-app-is-not-working-after-changing-package-name)

Comment: Thanks! I ran in to it for the same reason as well.

Comment: Thanks, saved me literally hours!

Answer (score 18):

Running `flutter clean` solved this issue for me using an emulator.

I wiped the emulator data, deleted my emulator, and created a new one, none of that worked. `flutter clean` worked though.

Comment: this also worked for me.. tried uninstallling by using setting, even using adb command but none of them works..

Comment: Wow This worked for me, my problem was that it stayed here: √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly i removed app with package name on command line. If you do not know package name you can check applicationId in app/build.gradle .

```
adb uninstall packagename
```

After then it works.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

1. First Install App using flutter run from terminal
2. When App is Installed. long press on app icon and go to app info.
3. Force stop app.
4. Remove cache and delete storage which is contained by app.
5. Uninstall App.
6. Install Again. it will work.

Comment: worked for me, but i did flutter clean and closed VSC after the above solution.

Comment: works for me. Booom

Answer (score 13):

If this problem persists in your physical device follow the below operation

Select the app from the apps list in settings
(You could see a "not installed for this user" sub along side it)

then 
`Top right menu button "uninstall for all users"`

Answer (score 8):

1. Open cmd in windows
2. Goto this location in cmd: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
3. Type this command: `adb uninstall com.example.application.name(Package name)`
4. Proceed if you see command success
5. Close and reopen your VS window
6. Run your flutter project again

Comment: Lol, it works, but why?

Comment: Dude, this worked, but why apk doesn't show on android device event if its there installed, and why do we need to manually uninstall it by cmd, please any one specify reason behind it

Comment: yeah, why does this work?

Comment: for mac users you do this: 


```
"cd /Users/[user]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

"./adb uninstall com.example.application.name"
```

Answer (score 7):

Very easy solution, just uninstall the app using below command even you did not found app on your device or emulator. This is because sometimes even you uninstall app from device from setting, that app still remains there for other users (Multi user feature in devices). So to completely remove the app from device, use below command and then try to install the app again (Restart the android studio to terminate process if it is already running)

```
adb uninstall <package.name>
```

e.g.

```
adb uninstall com.example.myfirstflutterapp
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with this when I uninstalled my app from a device, but unfortunately, I didn't uninstall it from all the users that are on my phone. Even Guest kept a version of my app in it, so I solve this issue with uninstalling all version of my app for all users. After that my app was installed without a problem. Sadly we don't get any error message that something is not right if this happens, so I hope this was a case for you guys and that I help you solve it! ;)

Answer (score 5):

***Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...***
is displayed in the **Run** tab and it doesn't give much information. Please have a look into the **Logcat** tab and here you can find detailed logs and you may find the reason why you are stuck. If **Logcat** tab is not visible, please refer this link:
[Android Studio not showing Logcat with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007784/android-studio-not-showing-logcat-with-flutter)

Comment: The best answer, I found out that the problem is from the Admob SDK. Thank you so much. There is a Logcat tab at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this problem when I commented all my bitmaps in `launch_background.xml`:

```xml
<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
<!--
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_320x480" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_480x320" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_480x800" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_800x480" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_720x1280" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_1280x720" />
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_1280x1920" />            
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_1920x1280" />  
-->          
</item>
```

I uncommented the bitmaps to get the Flutter build to run. I'm on:

`Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G4015, locale en-US)`

Comment: If you also comment the <item> tag, the problem is fixed.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Background: While the app was being installed by Android Studio, I manually deleted the app from the device. Thereafter I discovered that the app would not install.

This problem was resolved by going to Settings > Apps  and noting that the app was disabled rather than uninstalled even though I did confirm the uninstall request. In any case, I tapped the app and performed an uninstall from the Settings > Apps screen.

Answer (score 3):

On your real Android Device GO to **SETTINGS> APPS & NOTIFICATION(you can search it!) > APP INFO > chose the app of the current project > PRESS THE 3 dots > Uninstall for all user.**

Answer (score 2):

For anybody reading this, I solved this  by doing the following:

1. Open Android Studio->SDK Manager and install API 27 (By default
   Android Studio only installed the latest (API 28) as at the time of
   writing and there seem to be issues with using that right now).
2. In cmd run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and make sure you
   accept all the licenses.
3. Open Android Studio->AVD Manager and create a new emulator using API
   27
4. Run your app on the new emulator and enjoy!

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem because I changed a file (my_project\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\my_project\MainActivity.java). and I solved it like this:

```
package com.example.my_project; //your project name should be changed here.

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case problem was with installation of apk. Manual installation of apk works in my case

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it:

```
1. Power off & Close Android Emulator
2. Reopen Android Studio & go to Tools/ AVD Manager
3. In Virtual Devices List, click Dropdown icon > select 'Wipe Data'. Then click 'Launch this AVD...'
4. Waiting for VD open, then click Run in Android Studio
```

good luck

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a package: `admob_flutter`

I'd compiled and updated dependencies but used wrong the package. I realize it by looking at the Log in 
`View -> Tool Windows -> Logcat (ALT+6)` in Android Studio.

Before the app running in AVD was crashing, but I didn't know why, not seen an error in the Run Terminal, but the Logcat helped me.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I happened with me more than once, and every time I **restart** my mobile and this problem goes away, I used this solution when I tried all the solutions and fails

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answers here!
The one that worked for me -

replace contents of your `<app>/android/gradle.properties` with the following -

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.enableR8=true
```

If you don't want to enable R8

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
#android.enableR8=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` and check that the `android:name` was properly set with your package name. It worked for me while importing native code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MI phone and have turned on second space, i needed to delete the second space (of course i had no data there) to successfully install the apk again. Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63905079/11016892)

Answer (score 1):

When I switched system image for the emulator from Q to Pie it solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue when I uninstalled the flutter app from homescreen. I could not get it installed through android studio or through flutter install commands. What worked for me was to generate the release apk.

`flutter build apk`

And put the apk in the device and install it again manually through the device. After which there was no issues with installing through both android studio or flutter commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after I changed the package name. I fixed it by using [this guide](https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc)

In my case I did not have the java files as described in the article but did need to change the kotlin path similarly to the java path described.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have Guest User in your Device ... Go to that user uninstall the application from guest and then switch to your account and then try running it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO @nitinpoojary. I think your answer can be improved and looks truncated.

Comment: @Stefan Hegny there was some issue i guess while commenting but fixed thanks you for your notice.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

- delete **"build"** package
- apply **"flutter run"** command

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error occurs when I add the google firebase in my project, I tried all of the above solutions but not solved the problem,
At the end, I could solve this problem by installing the latest version of the Android API virtual device and google play services.

Answer (score 1):

Physical Device : I had the same issue when I uninstalled the app from app drawer.

As already answered, one way to fix this is using ADB to cleanly remove it from your phone, but if you don't have ADB installed, try :

1. Run flutter clean from the project root folder
2. Switch to the guest profile on your phone
   (You must have multiple users enabled, if not enable it in Settings by searching for 'users')
3. Delete the guest profile.
   (This can be done by swiping down the notification shade when you are in the guest profile --> clicking on the 'guest icon' next to the settings icon --> delete guest
4. run main.dart

Should be fixed

Answer (score 1):

On the Android physical device:

1. Unplug the USB cable.
2. Uninstall the app (from both personal and work profiles) / uninstall for all users (some devices only have this option).
3. Cleaned up (using an utility app) (optional).
4. Searched manually by the app name and delete them on the file explorer.
5. Restart.
6. Verify developer options are unable correctly.
   (After enabling as a developer,) check following developer options are enabled:

   - Developer options.
   - USB debugging.
   - Install via USB.
   - USB debugging(Security settings).
   - Select USB configuration: MTP(Media Transfer Protocol).

On the IDE:

1. Run `flutter clean`.
2. Restart the IDE (optional).
3. Plug the physical device and check the device is connected as debugging device.
4. Run `flutter pub get` and make sure no errors (optional).
5. Run in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

According to me this error is caused by some kind of memory leak or something else.So if you are using a physical device,
Restarting the physical device and re-installing the app afterwards worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use ADB to debug the app and sometimes it gets stuck on installing. I tried reinstalling VS Code and Flutter but found out the issue was with ADB.
So, whenever I face this issue I stop the ADB server by:

```
adb kill-server
```

and then connect to the device again and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the app's package name and if you think you did eveything right.
Don't forget to change folder name under

```
\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\
```

and also don't fotget to change package name inside `MainActivity.kt`

Answer (score 1):

**For AVD:** In case anyone facing the same problem on AVD then a cold boot may solve the issue as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is also happenning caused by flutter plugins that doesn't support android api 28.

In my case it caused by this plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me because there was a typo in gradle.properties. I assume it had something to do with the refactor tool in Android Studio. Two settings ended up on the same line like this:

```
android.enableJetifier = trueandroid.enableR8=true
```

When I fixed it, it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I closed my emulator and android studio and then restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue but I would like mention few things.
 1. My Fresh Installation was stuck at Installing APK...
 2. Same issue on Device as well as in Emulator

I realized that this issue is not device-specific for me. that's why I started looking for solutions.

Solution I tried 
1. Flutter Upgrade ( Using Fresh Copy from Flutter.dev) 
Didn't Solve my Issue
2. Android SDK (Using Fresh Android SDK)
Didn't Solve my Issue

Luckily, I found an article that explained you need to keep a few directories out from realtime scanning.
I was using FREE-Antivirus

I just tried to Uninstall that and Re-started my machine.

Guess What?
Issue Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

copy the Apk from **build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk** to your phone.

find the apk on phone and install it manually.

**flutter run** on will now work as expected.

Comment: This does not resolve being able to debug the application,only installing a debug build.

Comment: The flutter run command after manual installation once will launch app in debug mode.

Comment: without a debugger attached

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I created my first project. My solution would most probably work on a Xiaomi phone only. You should go to the developer options and then check the option "USB debugging(Security Settings)" under the Debugging menu and then your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by increasing the log buffer size in your Mobile Device or AVD.
This option will be available in the Developer Options Menu in the Settings of Your AVD or Mobile Device.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, **COLD BOOT** !! (must try before any complex processes)

In my case, I noticed the problem is with my emulator. Even without running any project, the emulator was stuck.  Hence same error occurred when I tried to run other projects also.
In case you are unable to do Cold boot for your AVD, follow below 2 steps and try again

1. Stop running your project(main.dart) and
2. delete the lock file at
   C:\Users\your_name.android\avd\Nexus_6P_API_30.avd\

Answer (score 0):

Settings>>Accounts and sync>>delete work profile, it will work!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this too and I found that the problem was I accidentally deleted kotlin/MainActivity. So I created a folder with package name, copied the MainActiviy from another project and put in it. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I uninstalled the app from all android profiles but this did not work, even after restarting the phone and clearing all cache.

What work I changed the package name, here you can see how to change the package name https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550358/1901574

Answer (score 0):

In my case actually, I noticed that the app was installed on my device but not launched automatically. I manually opened the app and then ran it again then that time it was reflected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is usually as simple as restarting the emulator using a **Cold Boot**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check if any space shortage is happened in emulator / device.It may happens when you have shortage of space.

If everything is fine ,then do as follow:

```
flutter clean
```

This will clean deletes build-cache which is in the /build folder.
Then run,

```
flutter pub get
```

For me this helped to resolve this issue.Hope it will help you too

Answer (score 0):

if you device is android 12+ then add this code in your android manifest file in  tag

```
android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when app crash immediately after apk installed to device, Just watch log and solve issue should work fine. In my case i set admob `APPLICATION_ID` wrong and that casuing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

From the notification badges select USB preference badge most probably indicating that device is charging via USB.[Notification badge for USB Preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZh13.png)
Once the preference open select File transfer under "Use USB for".
[USB Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLSbJ.png)
Now the apk should be able to install the run on the device connected.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vscode to code flutter, you should check if you have run it on main file

Answer (score 0):

**Based on here:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477867/12912487

I solved this issue by separating `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.action.VIEW` by different intent-filters in the `AndroidMainfest.xml`, as shown in the image below:

[image]

PS: I also run `flutter clean` and `flutter run` after this change.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone. I tried everything here and nothing worked. The issue was as a result of missing package name in my android app manifest file, this was most likely a merge issue:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sentrified">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I uninstalled the app from the device manually and tried to install using

```
flutter install
flutter run
```

all other apps were installed and working normally but he app I uninstalled was not installing from flutter command line or adb.

> RCA: The app was not uninstalled properly so some files were there due
> to which app was neither updating nor uninstalling.

Uninstall the app completely using adb command

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

If using MAC then need to add path to zshrc to execute adb commands

```
echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I disabled play protect on simulator and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running in the emulator, try Wipe Data in AVD Manager

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

Answer enable Developer options?

1. Enter Settings -> More settings -> About phone (Version);
2. Click seven times on Software version;
3. Developer options will appear in Settings -> More settings.

Answer (score -1):

This was issue for me. On the device, open `Settings` > `Apps` > Find your app & select it > Click on `...` at top right > Delete for all users. Once complete, run again and it should install

If it's still showing `Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...` in the console after this, go to the emulator and click your app icon, it should open.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me 
Step 1: Run `flutter clean` (this will delete your build directory) 
Step 2: Run/Debug the application on Emulator/Physical Device

Answer (score -3):

I tried all the solutions above didn't work

**I tried running the app from the main.dart file it worked for me**

Answer (score -4):

You can use:

```
flutter build apk --release 

flutter install
```

Comment: this does not resolve the issue, this will create a release build and install that without any debugging capabilities.