# Flutter run stuck at Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

**Edit: It seemed to work after restarting everything, no other solution really noticed.**

I couldn't find useful solutions on following thread:

[Flutter stuck at Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394504/flutter-stuck-at-installing-build-app-outputs-apk-app-apk)

It's not the same issue, mine doesn't finish installing.

I have an Honor 7 as a connected device and using Visual Studio Code.

When running 'flutter run' following happens:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on PLK L01 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1,1s
Resolving dependencies...                                    3,3s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         15,6s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                     -
```

Once last step is loading, my device asks to accept app installation. Once accepted it provides 2 options after installation:

- Open App
- Finish ( Meaning = return to home screen )

Either way the last step doesn't finish. 'flutter clean' makes no difference. Hot reload not working. Did anyone else encounter this issue ?

---

'flutter doctor -v' output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at F:\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-P, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 2.2)
    • Android Studio at E:\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2017.3)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    • Dart plugin version 173.4127.31
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.12.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.22.3

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • PLK L01 • H8WDU15207300112 • android-arm64 • Android 6.0 (API 23)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. It is happening after flutter upgrade.

Comment: I too face this issue. I just click on stop and then run the app again.

Comment: I am too facing this issue still no help working

Comment: I am now facing this issue. `Flutter 1.17.4`

Comment: @MaylorTaylor did you fix this ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

Solutions is **quite simple**

For flutter **hot reload** **problems** that may be happening with your project,

It is a problem with your **device**, and not **flutter** or **Android Studio**

This happens when your **logcat** **hangs up**.

You might want to **increase** your **buffer size**.

To do this, go into your **device** or **emulator**:

**Settings > Developer options** (*Ensure they are turned on*),

Change the buffer size to a higher number.

Then run **flutter run -v** again

Comment: Thanks, increasing buffer size, reduce install build time.

Comment: this helped me after week of stuck this error, thanks mate

Answer (score 6):

Other user may get solution in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist).
In my case the app **uninstalled manually** so it is not showing in launcher .
and got solution in this
**[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist)**.

which is

1. Go to **Settings**.
2. Go to **Apps**.
3. Select your app. (here, you can verifythat your app is not uninstalled properly).
4. Open the **overflow menu** (which are 3 dots)on the top right and select Uninstall for all users.

Comment: Thanks, the issue seems to happen when there are multiple users in the device. Manually uninstalling from launcher only removes the app from the current user.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that I forgot to change MainActivity.kt package name after I modified it.

```
package com.WrongCompanyName.WrongProjectName

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted but clearly flutter doesn't give an error if the java package is wrong, so I had the same issue, thanks.

Comment: Same here, this is obviously the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `MainActivity.java` is in the right location, it has a `MainActivity` class declaration, and that the package matches your package id.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** You can enter this in the terminal

```
flutter run
```

And then `r` to hot reload. You might have to Ctrl+C and n first

It's slower than F5, but still works!

[image]

**My original answer:**
I got around this problem by typing the command in the Terminal

```
flutter run -d <deviceId>
```

for my LG phone, it was

```
flutter run -d LGUS998d7315d51
```

Comment: for me it was the only way to run my app in a real device, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! `flutter run` also works, and you can enter `r` to hot reload

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to check the `package` name (iOS is `applicationId`) of my Android App.
I had recently changed the name of my package from the default "com.example.app_name" to something more custom. However, I had forgotten to change all of the locations.

I believe the most important locations are as follows:
**Mac / iOS**

- `build.gradle` -- search for "applicationId"

**Android**

- `[app_name]\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`
- `[app_name]\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`
- `[app_name]\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml`

Just search for `package="`

Answer (score 1):

Open **android\app\build.gradle** and set a different application id to the app.

```
defaultConfig {
  // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
  applicationId "com.othervalue.sbmicalc"
}
```

Then remove previous build:

```
flutter clean
```

and run again:

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this off and on for a year, here is what I just noticed that makes it work or not work on my system.

**I discovered tonight that if I have my virus protection running my emulator stalls in the

" --->**    ***Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.*** 
and I just get a white screen. I turn off the virus protection and it works fine in debug mode. 
If its on I have to keep going to the terminal and doing: " flutter run " to see any changes I have made. 
Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and found a solution.(I use emulator)

It seems this is just an emulator problem.

`AVD Manager -> Actions -> Wipe Data`

Maybe you need to do `flutter clean`, but the problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not uninstalled the flutter app properly from mobile phone because my mobile has normal space and private space...so when I uninstall the app from normal space it was uninstalled but not uninstall from private space. then after removing the app from private space and run

```
flutter clean
```

and run the again it's work fine!

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue when I have changed targetSdkVersion to static values (33) in my case

```
android/app/build.gradle

targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion to targetSdkVersion 33
```

So, By un-doing changes and by adding constant in local.properties worked for me

```
android/app/build.gradle

targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

and

```
android/local.properties

flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.targetSdkVersion=33
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see your app installed like this -> just click it to open. It worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens with me also whenever I delete an app from the phone.
The simple solution is:

1. Get the build apk file.
2. Run:

```
flutter build apk --release
```

3. Install that app in the phone and re run the code.