# Stuck at installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk in Flutter... after uninstalling the app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54701359/11594030) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53394504/11594030), but nowhere could I find a good answer. I have a problem when I try to run the app. Initially it was working completely fine, but I uninstalled my app from my Android device for some reason and now when I try to run the app on my Android phone it is stuck at *installing* build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...

[image: llutt]

PS: it also successfully installs at my friend's device. It is only stuck when I try to run in my phone. Also other projects are successfully loaded too, but I even tried to create a new project and copy all files from the old one and tried to run, but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: Invalidate Caches and Restart :)

Comment: please be more descriptive i m begineer to flutter

Comment: @AR tried but not working

Comment: okay try using flutter clean and then run using flutter run in terminal

Comment: i tried that before asking it here  that didn't worked forme

Comment: I had this very same problem and it was related to the users on the device. If you have multiple users on the device and uninstall manually for one user, the app won't install automatically till you uninstall the app for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` and check if you have enough memory on your device.

Comment: Can you please show your `flutter doctor` output?

Also, are you able to install a build manually by `adb install build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`?

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by typing this command in the Terminal:

```
flutter run -d <deviceId>
```

For my [LG phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_Electronics#Mobile_phones), it was:

```
flutter run -d LGUS998d7315d51
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs if your device has an incomplete installed app with the same package name.

**Solution**:

1. Uninstall any app in your device that has the same package name
2. See the *Settings/app* whether it is completely uninstalled or not. If not, uninstall from there also.
3. If possible, erase your internal storage.
4. Push your project to GitHub
5. Delete the project from your harddisk.
6. Download the project and unzip it
7. Run it

I lost all four days regarding this problem. I tried all the solutions I found. But at last I solved this issue by doing the above things.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions in the previous answers.

What worked for me: just restart your physical device. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by

1. run `flutter clean` in external terminal (windows).
2. completely delete your app in mobile (from storage and private space if have) settings -> app -> selected your app and click "uninstall from all users"
3. run `flutter run` in external terminal it's work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Restart vs code/android studio
3. Restart your device
4. Run with `flutter run` or crtl + F5 for vs code

Answer (score 0):

Just go to File in Android Studio and click on

```
  Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by incomplete installation of the app.
I have solved this problem by uninstalling the app from the device using **Terminal**.

Type in: adb uninstall **app_package_name** in the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issues, I solved this by copying the apk file into my device internal memory and installed it back.

The apk file location  build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk