# Flutter stuck at Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk after changing and reverting back to original meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, debugging, flutter, dart

I was trying to use firebase_admob and I changed meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml file. I undo the changes and file now have the below as original.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

Now I am facing the issue on debugging my app, I am stuck at `Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...`

My Debug Console shows: `√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.`

I have performed `flutter clean`, wiped my Emulator data.

After trying to debug, It again gets stuck at `Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...`

It shows a white screen for some mini seconds and gets stuck.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.bfdi_app">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="WBH App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post you **Android Manifest** code

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: DId you remove the firebase_admob from pubspec?

Comment: No, I did not removed it.

Comment: Ok!  Have you called firebase_admob lib from any of your dart file?

Comment: No, but I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468333/11545939

Comment: That's great!! Sometimes these happen for actually no reason. Carry on!!