# Flutter - android folder showing as android[mi_card_android] in project structure

Tags: android, flutter

After run project 1st time it working fine but after uninstall app and try to reinstall it
not working please check screenshot. Device also connected and showing process bar when click on run
process showing at botton but not running in device or emulator too.

I have created new project but same happning with every project.

Comment: add more details and screenshots

Comment: Go resolved helped by

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394504/flutter-stuck-at-installing-build-app-outputs-apk-app-apk