# Flutter app not running on physical device

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, mobile-application

I have installed flutter and android studio, after uninstalling it way back, now I am trying to run this app on my phone just to check if everything is okay or not. But nothing is being shown on my phone and it's been nearly 30 minutes since i am trying it. The terminal outputs :

Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk

Please provide some solution so that my app can run little quicker on my device.

Comment: Your gradle binaries are downloading, it will happen only once and subsequent builds will be faster, use the built in emulator for this, this will help you to leave your station unattended

Comment: Are you using a cable or wifi? `Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk` is not an error message, it means that it is currently installing something.

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394504/flutter-stuck-at-installing-build-app-outputs-apk-app-apk